# When pilots check in with a different controller, how to reference flight level?

Tags: air-traffic-control, phraseology

When pilots check in with a different controller after they are handed off, how do they report their current altitude in flight levels if they are in level flight or a climb / descent? I feel like saying "***level*** flight level" could be misunderstood.

Can pilots omit the "flight level" phraseology in the examples below?

"(ATC Facility) Baron x-ray five x-ray sierra ***level*** flight level two-five-zero... " (level flight @ FL250)

"(ATC Facility) Baron x-ray five x-ray sierra flight level two-five-zero ***climbing*** flight level three-two-zero..."

"(ATC Facility) Baron x-ray five x-ray sierra flight level two-five-zero ***descending*** flight level two-zero-zero..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't say which country you're interested in, but in the US the standard phraseology is indeed to use "level" twice. This is from [the AIM 5-3-1](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/media/aim.pdf):

> When operating in a radar environment: On initial contact, the pilot
>   should inform the controller of the aircraft’s assigned altitude
>   preceded by the words “level,” or “climbing to,” or “descending to,”
>   as appropriate; and the aircraft’s present vacating altitude, if
>   applicable
>
> **EXAMPLE −
>
>   1.** (Name) CENTER, (aircraft identification), LEVEL (altitude or flight level).

Per 4-2-9, the correct way to state a flight level is:

> At and above 18,000 feet MSL (FL 180), state the words “flight level”
>   followed by the separate digits of the flight level.

So put all that together and you get something like this:

> Indianapolis Center, N12345 level flight level 210

Practically, I hear a lot of pilots omit the words "flight level", perhaps because they seem superfluous:

> Indianapolis Center, N12345 level at 210

As for misunderstanding, personally I think that's unlikely even if you use the word "level" twice. A flight level is stated as three digits ("two one zero") whereas an altitude always includes the units, i.e. thousands and hundreds ("five thousand five hundred").

Comment: The reason to state the altitude on initial contact with a facility is to VERIFY that what the controller is seeing is accurate -- which it is 99.9% of the time. So if you're level, he knows that & can see that because your altitude block isn't changing. So the salient point being communicated is the "210" part. I'd always include "flight level" since 210 can also be a heading, or an airspeed. But "level" is often omitted -- "Center, N12345, flight level 210" communicates everything the controller needs, without the messy "level flight level" phrase.

Comment: I was listening to a liveatc.net broadcast and heard "level flight level", and accepting this as the answer since it's backed up with a reference.

Answer (score 3):

The word 'maintaining' is used, not 'level'. Using your example it would be:

- (ATC Facility) Baron X5XS <strike>level</strike> maintaining FL 250.

The pilot can say maintaining if they're expecting higher/lower, otherwise omit maintaining altogether:

- (ATC Facility) Baron X5XS FL 250.

If climbing/descending:

- (ATC Facility) Baron X5XS climbing/descending FL 100.

On the first contact with a radar service, for example going from tower to departure, the SID and passing altitude are also mentioned:

- (ATC Facility) Baron X5XS on the STACK 1C passing 2300 for FL 60.

In a busy environment you may be asked to 'report call sign only', in this case:

- (ATC Facility) Baron X5XS

Local guidelines should also be used if different. I couldn't find examples in ICAO Annex 10 and Doc 4444, but clear examples are in the UK's [Radiotelephony Manual](https://publicapps.caa.co.uk/modalapplication.aspx?catid=1&pagetype=65&appid=11&mode=detail&id=6973) (click image below to view).

[image]